# Laravel Compare Carbon Date format from DB with Javascript Current Date

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am currently using a Datatable js script for displaying my data in my blade.php. I want to compare the created_at column with the current system date and change the row of data's colour to red if it is before the current date. However all of my row of datas are changed to red, even if the data's date is the same as the current date. I have formatted my database date to be Carbon::parse($date)->toDateString() and change the current date format I get in my javascript to be toDateString() format as well.

Below are my javascript codes on the blade.php

```
    let date = new Date();
    now = date.toDateString();

    var ordersTable = $('#orders_table').DataTable({ 
        stateSave: true,
        "rowCallback": function(row, data, index){
            if(data[1] < now){
                $(row).css('color', 'red');
            }
            else{
                $(row).css('color', 'green');
            }
        },
```

Below is a screen capture of the dummy data I have:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vwens.png)

Hopefully I am able to bring across the question clearly

Comment: Can you add rows data that returns from the server. In this case `Carbon::parse($date)->toDateString()` must be different format with what you have in javascript. In order to compare string dates in javascript, they both should be same format.

Comment: I guess `data[1]` contains "Y-m-d" format on php side and you compare this with `Fri Mar 05 2021` this format in javascript?

Comment: Hi thx for the comment Alex, I think it is working now! I used this format for my php side `Carbon::parse($date)->format('D M d Y');`

Comment: I also changed the if comparison condition to `if (data[1] !== now)` for it to work, if i use the `<` operator it does not work for some reason

Comment: It would be great to keep habit comparing object date instead of string to avoid such strange issues.

Comment: I tired comparing object date in the first place and it didn't work hence I use the `toDateString()` format. Unless I have made some mistakes for the object date method as well

Comment: You must be wrong otherwise Javascript has internal bugs. lol